# An extension which enables alt + t shortcut for quickly change into .ts file with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, shortcut

I formatted my computer and used to use something on vs code which enables 3 shortcuts when u open a file of a component:

`Alt + t` = switch to typescript file of the same component
`Alt + c` = switch to css (or sass) file of the same component
`Alt + h` = switch to html file of the same componente

Now i can't find the extension or nothing that has the same behavior

Do anyone have a clue on what was i using?

i do code with angular on vs code and this shortcuts was very helpful

I did tried searching on google and the most popular angular extensions, but no shortcuts like these

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you were using the `Angular Files` vscode extension

Comment: Tried it already but doesn't worked

Answer (score 0):

with [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) you can create key bindings to open the related files.